# Language Support in 18.04 not working org.freedesktop.PolicyKitError.Failed

Tags: 18.04, language-support, policykit

I believe that after upgrade to 18.04 Lubuntu I have a common root problem which affects many things. Looks like no application, which would require root privileges could open. For example, Synaptics and Fcitx just can't be started, without showing any diagnostics, any launch attempt would just silently die in 30 seconds. Time and Date Settings have 'Unlock'-ed button, but when I hit it, nothing happens.

But best wrongful behavior is with the Language Support (not working). When I start it, it gives following messages:

> Checking available language support...
>   Language Support is not installed correctly.
>   I press Install, and get:
>   Could not install the full language support.
>   Details:
>   org.freedesktop.PolicyKitError.Failed:('system-bus-name',{'name': ':1.32'}): ord.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
>   I press Close, and get:
>   You are not allowed to perform this action (You don't have the required priviliges to perform this action).
>   In Details looks like it tries to show (a part of) the same message > :org.freedesktop.PolicyKitError.Failed:('system-bus-name'
>   I press Close, and it loops to the top of the cycle (Checking available language support...)

Please help!

Comment: Can you please run `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` and let us know if it makes a difference.

Comment: Lubuntu-core is/was installed. I try to keep it to bare minimum so don't want the full lubuntu-desktop metapackage. Instead I installed lxpolkit (it was not!), and it seemed to fix (most of the) problem, so I'm good for now. This is definitely a policykit (known) problem.

Comment: PolicyKit fixed but Language still does not work.

Comment: Translate "Language ... does not work." Exactly what did you try to do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: I try to use it, to switch input languages by Clt-Space. Yesterday somtimes it worked now it does not. fcitx-diagnose says that my env vars such as QT_IM_MODULE are set up wrong, to 'xim' instead of 'fcitx'. I wonder where are these are set up?

Comment: It looks to me as if you want to use the Lubuntu desktop, so then please install `lubuntu-desktop` instead of experimenting with some kind of minimal install. I'm disinclined to help you sort multiple issues which may well simply be the result of missing packages.

Comment: I'm not experimenting anything. I had a standard perfectly working Lubuntu 16.04 which I unfortunately upgraded thru the standard Ubuntu channel to 18.04. I've answered all your questions but did not receive any help so far. If you can't help, could you point me to somebody who can? Who can at least tell me where the fcitx environment variables are set up (my .profile and the like has nothing)? Do I need to grep thru the source code myslef?!

Comment: The description of the `lubuntu-desktop` package says: "It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades"... Anyway, you can run the command `im-config -n fcitx` to get the proper Fcitx variables at next login.

Comment: Thank you for im-config advice. I have tried it yesterday but give it a try again. It does nothing (goes back to ready with no response). No env vars are changed. As I wrote before I have a standard Lubuntu installation. lubuntu-core is installed. As to the lubuntu-desktop - it might have be installed (it's hard to say since it's a meta-package). I got idiotic omnious warnings about missing 'o11y' in .services during the 18.04 upgrage, but what does it mean?

Comment: That command is not supposed to produce any terminal output, but it creates the file `~/.xinputrc` which in turn affects certain environment variables at login. But only if certain Fcitx packages are installed, and the easiest way to ensure that is to install one of the CJKV languages via _Language Support_... You seem to have issues with your system which go far beyond the topic of your question above. I'd recommend that you ask a new question to get proper help to sort it.

Comment: My (re-)created file .xinputrc in home directory has only one uncommented line: run_im fcitx, and obviously it cannot set (or fix) any wrong env vars. I agree that my notebook has a root level problem (that's what I wrote in my original post... oh, if people could only read what's written rather than youtubed... oh, well :)

Comment: When I ran fcitx-imlist -l command, I get a Warning and Critical errors. Warning is again about the DBus (ServiceUnknown: org.fcitx.Fcitx-0 was not provided by any .service files), and Glib-CRITICAL: g_ptr_array_forereach: assertion 'array' failed. I don't know much about this weird Ubuntu (Dbus and fcitx) architecture, so can't figure out what topic for a new question should I formulate (what system part exactly is broken, Dbus?), so maybe you could help me with that? And I will start a new topic then.

Comment: BTW what are the CJKV languages?

Comment: Oh, CJKV languages are Chinese, Japanese and others, used to be called Asian languages when we programmed them then.. I reinstalled my Russian language there several times, that should be bad enough to reinstall the Fctix packages..

Comment: I installed `lubuntu-desktop`, which got things unstuck for me. I had to logout and log back in for the changes to take effect. At that point root permission prompts started working again, which enabled the Language Support window to install necessary missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 after installing xfce4.

The problem was that no PolicyKit Authentication Agent was installed - or at least not one that xfce recognised.

The solution is to install one:

```
$ sudo apt install policykit-1-gnome
```

That's it.

.

That installed the package: /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.

It seemed to update the autostart list.

It was necessary to restart. Because running the file from terminal didn't work. Someone had written somewhere to run it from an xterm. I had run it from the terminal emulator that comes default in Ubuntu and is still default after installing xfce: gnome terminal.

There is such a thing as '[xfce-polkit](https://github.com/ncopa/xfce-polkit)' and '[xfce-polkit-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xfce-polkit-git/)'.

But Debian [reports](https://packages.debian.org/sid/policykit-1-gnome), in it's account of the package policykit-1-gnome, that xfce still uses the gnome polkit agent:

> This implementation was originally designed for GNOME 2, but most
>   GNOME-based desktop environments, including GNOME 3, GNOME Flashback,
>   and MATE, have their own built-in PolicyKit agents and no longer use
>   this one. The remaining users of this implementation are Cinnamon,
>   XFCE and Unity.

Other accounts of this problem:

http://lovingthepenguin.blogspot.com/2016/10/fixing-packagekit-authentication-in.html
https://fransdejonge.com/2017/01/fix-no-gksudo-permissions-prompt-on-gparted-synaptic-mounting-drives-etc-in-debian/